# Maven build is failing with error could not find artifact

Tags: maven, pom.xml, artifactory, maven-dependency

I have a project demo-parent which contains 2 subprojects child1 and child2.
demo-parent is building a pom.
child1 and child2 are building one jar each. And all these are getting uploaded to the artifactory.
demo-parent(also used flatten plugin)

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.demos</groupId>
  <artifactId>demo-parent</artifactId>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <version>${revision}</version>
  <properties>
   <revision>1.0-SNAPSHOT</revision>
  </properties>
...
</project>
```

child1  and child 2

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.demos</groupId>
  <artifactId>child1</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <parent>
      <groupId>com.demos</groupId>
      <artifactId>demo-parent</artifactId>
      <version>${revision}</version>
  </parent>
  <properties>
   <revision>1.0-SNAPSHOT</revision>
  </properties>
...
</project>
```

This project is building and uploading fine. Now when I use this child1 or child2 as a dependency in other projects, it fails with the error:
`Failed to execute goal on project maven-webapp: could not resolve dependencies for the project com.demos:maven-webapp:war:1.01: Failed to collect dependencies at com.demos:child1:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.demos:child1:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.demos:demp-parent:pom:{revision} in artifactory` .

I am not getting why it is searching for `com.demos:demo-parent:pom:{revision}`, even if searching why revision is not getting replaced by 1.0-SNAPSHOT as I have used `<revision>1.0-SNAPSHOT</revision>` in child1.

Comment: Have you configured the flatten-maven-plugin as described in the documentation https://maven.apache.org/maven-ci-friendly.html

Comment: There was an issue with the use of flatten plugin. Now working fine